# Approach for Core Data + GCD for complex background data handling

Tags: core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How can you use Core Data and GCD when the methods that get called within the background thread need many different `NSManagedObject`s? You as the caller might not have insight which objects will be needed in the sub-calls?

Think of a complex download, parsing and saving procedure with many managed objects, helper methods for dates, statuses and so on. When you start your background thread with GCD, a new `NSManagedObjectContext` will be needed, that's for sure. But you are not able to tell what managed objects will be needed by every sub-method. So, do you need to pass the context to every single helper method, e.g. for just telling a `NSDate` difference?

Is there an easy approach that doesn't blow up the lines of code?

Comment: AFAIK each managed object carries his own managed object context, so passing the object to various methods is enough. Also - you may want to implement methods as instance methods in custom subclass for managed object's entity.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that could fit the bill of not blowing up the code could be to receive your data in your various background threads and code it all into dictionaries. If you use JSON as the transfer format, that would be very few lines of code.

Then you could pass it all to a block on the main thread to create the managed object and insert it into the managed object context. Again, that would not carry much overhead, compared to a single-threaded solution.